# Statistics Collector Policy-Not able to add custom dimensions-used javaScript to set ContextVariable

Tags: javascript

I have used JavaScript Policy to set a variable from the json request and am trying to add the same in custom Attribites.Dono where am missing !!

**Js**

> var payload = context.getVariable('request.content');
>
> var data =JSON.parse(payload);
>
> context.setVariable("ItemName",data.Item_name);

**Statistics collector Policy**

```
<Statistics>
    <Statistic name="itemName" ref="ItemName" type="STRING">value</Statistic>
</Statistics>
```

Unable to see the Custom Attribute(itemName) in Reports tab.

Thanks in adv!!

Comment: Please clarify your issue. It's currently unclear.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom report using Custom Dimension

Comment: Wherein am creating that custom attribute in a proxy and the request to that proxy is a json payload. i am using Js to extract the ItemName from the payload and setting it as a custom attribute using StatisticCollector policy. But am unable to view that custom attribute in the Reports section.